# Is it possible to avoid getting NotifyingMulticolumnSplitViewController and SFAuthenticationViewController with Firebase analytics & swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to set up Firebase analytics for my swiftui project, i already use AnalyticsEventScreenView, but i continue getting NotifyingMulticolumnSplitViewController in firebase_screen_class value in analytics ? how can i avoid getting it ?  [Analytics debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvQIj.png)}

```
class AnalyticsMgr {

enum ErrorType: String {
    case signIn = "error_login"
    case signUp = "error_sign_up"
    case facebookAuth = "error_auth_facebook"
    case createProfile = "error_create_profile"
}

static func logScreen(screenName: String, screenClass: String) {
    Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView, parameters:
                        [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: screenName,
                         AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: screenClass])
}

static func logLoginSuccess(method: String) {
    Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventLogin, parameters: [AnalyticsParameterMethod: method])
}

static func logSignUpSuccess(method: String) {
    Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSignUp, parameters: [AnalyticsParameterMethod: method])
}

static func logError(type: ErrorType, description: String) {
    Analytics.logEvent("error", parameters: ["type" : type.rawValue, "description" : description])
}
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled** to **NO** (boolean) in your info.plist.

This should prevent the Firebase Analytics SDK from automatically log those NotifyingMulticolumnSplitViewController Screen Views.

Source:
https://adswerve.com/blog/a-new-approach-to-firebase-screenview-tracking/
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/google-analytics-manual-screen-view.html